# auto send a message to a caller

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know that is there any way to implement an application in iPhone in which if an application runs there is a button in that application .and a user is busy (lets say he is driving  a car) .and he click on that button .and if during this time any caller calls then a auto message send to that caller like "I am busy. I will call you later" .and when a user release a button then it will not work

Please guide me it is possible or not and if it is then how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't provide API for calls. You can't programmatically sent sms or deny calls.

Moreover, iOS 6 have new feature "Do Not Disturb": http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5463 . This feature makes something like you said.

Comment: but i want to run it in my own application

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible to do this on iOS from third party app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Without user interaction an app is not allowed to sent messages from iOS devices.

You can only sent messages from your app using `MFMessageComposer`, but user must press send button for sending the message. You can only compose a message for the user.

Also the most important thing, you can't deny incoming calls using your app. There is no public API is provided for doing this.

Comment: ok thankyou but it will run inmy own application

Comment: There is API for detecting calls: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604

Comment: @ArtemKalachev: thanks for the link, but there is no API for denying calls.